# Is it possible to defer interpolation of array of template literals in javascript till it's used in a loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, templates, literals

is there a way I can have an array of template literals and run a function to generate the interpolated string in loop thru another array? If I define my array of template strings I get an error saying the variable is not defined.

for example I'd like to have something like this:

```js
var classes = {
  ....stuff here
}

var templateUrlsToFetch = [
  `api${classId}/rooms/${roomId}/instructors`,
  `api${classId}/rooms/${roomId}/reports`,
  `api${classId}/rooms/${roomId}/records`,
  `api${classId}/rooms/${roomId}/reports/${reportId}`,
  `api${classId}/rooms/${roomId}/reports/${reportId}?format=json`
];



classes.forEach((classObj) => {
  var classId = class.Id;

  classObj.rooms.forEach((room) => {
    var roomId = room.id;

    room.report.forEach((report) => {
      var reportId = report.id;

      templateUrlsToFetch.forEach((url) => {
        console.log(url);
      });

    });
  });

});
```

Comment: You have some mistakes in your code. I tried to fix it and created a jsbin. [http://jsbin.com/higohezezo/edit](http://jsbin.com/higohezezo/edit?js,console) . See if it helps and try to improve your example please.